# Restrict bandwidth in specific devices [wifi]

Tags: bandwidth, wifi

I wanted to restrict my wifi's bandwidth in some particular devices (specifically android). I searched up, and found **QoS** as a solution. But, as far as I have seen, QoS divides bandwidth on basis of priority. Means, if a laptop (with medium priority) and an android (with low priority) are connected to wlan, the android device gets low bandwidth.
But as soon as laptop is disconnected, android again consumes the maximum available bandwidth.

I wish to restrict bandwidth in terms of figures (Eg: 1Mbps for Wlan devices). Is there any way out to achieve this?

I'm using TP-LINK W8961ND modem.

Comment: Anyone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standards-based mechanism to do this. You need your wifi modem/router to provide this function in software. Many do in the enterprise market but not in the residential/SOHO market.

If your "modem" is not your router, you could also do it on your gateway device and only shape traffic going over the internet. For example pfsense is perfect for this.